# Sudo nano problem

Tags: raspbian, ssh, retropie, terminal, putty

[image: the command I tried but failed]

I run the command in the screen shot though ssh to my raspberry pi. All I get is a blank file. I know the file exists, and has code in it, but nano must've not understood me. Here is what I get when I "ls". [image: what is inside the folder]Can anyone give me the correct terminal command? My pi that I'm sshing to runs the official RetroPie image. I'm using putty as my SSH program.

Comment: Cute woof but a copy / paste of the error is easier to read.  My guess the name is wrong.  Try to use tab to complete the name rather than single quotes (not even sure that works). Part type each bit then use tab to complete the rest and when you get to the file name just type D and press tab.  If there are multiple files Or directories beginning the same pressing tab twice will list them for you - just add a few more characters and try tab again.  e.g. /etc/fs then press tab will complete the file /etc/fstab where as /boot/co tab will not complete as config.txt and configs/ exist

Comment: So you will need to type config. or configs to complete using the tab

Comment: Why is there a space before `.cfg` ?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. They are unreadable. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: @Michael-Harvey I'm trying to quote what it said in the "ls".

Comment: Does the file name really have all those spaces? Why don't you either use tab-completion, or copy the filename from the output of ls (adding quotes at start and end)?

Comment: @ Michael-Harvey I'm sorry what is tab completion?

Comment: @UNKNOWN - please see the first comment (starting cute woof) where I try to explain tab completion...

Comment: @Andyroo Can you give me an example? I still do not understand.

Comment: In the example I will spell out tab and the space bar - type sudo space nano space / b tab tab - that will list two options /bin and /boot then press o and tab and the system will complete the word boot for you. Then type cm tab and the file name cmdline.txt will be completed.  Now delete the whole line as that’s not a file to mess with!  This is for Raspbian Buster.

Comment: @Andyroo I still can't get into that folder. Can you give an example of the command to open the DragonRise .cfg file  that is in the folder? (The one in the screenshot)

Comment: Without the text it will be hard (I’m not running the retro pi software) but as the file name is the issue can you run a `ls` command on that directory and put the result in the question unless there are thousands of files. You can use https://www.tecmint.com/15-basic-ls-command-examples-in-linux/ to understand the ls command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as it turns out I did not put the correct number of spaces between word on the file name. After I corrected this it worked fine.